# Sporadic Results from adLDAP

Tags: php, adldap

I have installed and configured adLDAP.

I have a very small script that simply outputs the groups a user belongs to. The issue I am having is that about every other call to the groups method fails. My code is:

```
<?php

require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/src/adLDAP.php');
$adldap = new adLDAP();

try {
    $adldap = new adLDAP();
    echo "Connect Success<br />";
}
catch (adLDAPException $e) {
    echo $e;
    exit();   
}
$username = str_replace("MYDOMAIN\\","",$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']);
echo $username.'<br />';
try {
    $user = $adldap->authenticate('admin', 'password');
    echo "Authenticate Success<br />";
} catch (adLDAPException $e) {
    echo $e; 
    exit();
}
try {
    $members = $adldap->user()->inGroup($username,'MYGROUP');
    echo "Read Groups Success<br />";
} catch (adLDAPException $e) {
    echo $e; 
    exit();
}
if($members) {
    echo 'In Group';
} else {
    echo 'Not in Group';
}
```

Everything works fine until I hit the last code section. Sometimes it returns "In Group", sometimes "Not In group".  If I choose a group the user is NOT in, it return "Not In Group" every time.

Anyone have a suggestions as to why its sporadic when it is a group the user DOES belong to?